# How to change schema name from the flyway sql script file dynamically while generating build

Tags: flyway

In my project, there are several flyway migration sql script file. Now my project's database name has been changed so if i will change the database name in all the file then it will throw error such like -

Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 2018.12.10.132421584
-> Applied to database : 988067673
-> Resolved locally : -1477366160

So How to change the database name without modifying the flyway sqlm script file?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your migration in loop and change the database by passing it for each migration, i know this is the low performance approach but it should work.